# Can't get different speeds for game players in turtle module

Tags: python, performance, turtle-graphics

I can not get the right speed for bad and good players in this Minigame off YouTube called 'Falling Skies": [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Ralph94/c4dad62b4e78aa8a14c1d299fad3454e) which uses the Python turtle module.  How do I fix this? (I got stuck on Part 6 of the Minigame tutorial.)

```
import turtle # Our module's
import random

# Screen
ms = turtle.Screen()
ms.title("Falling Piece's mini_game by Rafa94")
ms.bgcolor("purple")
ms.setup(width=800, height=600)
ms.tracer(0)

#player
player = turtle.Turtle()
player.speed(0)
player.shape("turtle")
player.color("blue")
player.penup()
player.goto(0, -250) # y is postive in the up direction y is negative in the down direction
player.direction = "stop"

# create a list of good players # good represents good_player
goods =[]#Empty list

#Addgood players
for _  in range(20): # we are making a set of 20 players
    good = turtle.Turtle() # we want the other player basically across from each other thats we copyed the code one on -y and one on +y (first player in the bottom, second player on top of Screen)
    good.speed(0)
    good.shape("circle")
    good.color("red")
    good.penup()
    good.goto(0, 250) # y is postive in the up direction y is negative in the down direction
    good.speed = random.randint(5,8)
    goods.append(good)

# create a list of bad players # bad represents bad_players
bads = []  # Empty list

# Addbad players
for _ in range(20):  # we are making a set of 20 players
        bad = turtle.Turtle()  # we want the other player basically across from each other thats we copyed the code one on -y and one on +y (first player in the bottom, second player on top of Screen)
        bad.speed(10)
        bad.shape("circle")
        bad.color("yellow")
        bad.penup()
        bad.goto(0, 250) # y is postive in the up direction y is negative in the down direction
        bad.speed = random.randint(5, 8)
        bads.append(bad)

#Functions
def go_left():
    player.direction = "left"

def go_right():
    player.direction = "right"

#keyboard Binding
ms.listen() # it is bascally saying listen for keyboard input < ^ >
ms.onkeypress(go_left, "Left")
ms.onkeypress(go_right, "Right")

#Main game loop # while something is true it will repeat
while True:
    # update screen
    ms.update()
    #Move player
    if player.direction == "left":
        x = player.xcor()
        x -= + 3
        player.setx(x)
    if player.direction == "right":
        x = player.xcor()
        x += + 3
        player.setx(x)

    # Move Good Player
    for good in goods:
        y = good.ycor()
        y -= good.speed # We want the ball to be falling at a smooth speed
        good.sety(y)

    # Check it off the Screen
    if y < -300:
            x = random.randint(-380, 380)
            y = random.randint(300, 400)
            good.goto(x, y)

    # check for collision with player
    if good.distance(player) < 20:
           x = random.randint(-380, 380)
           y = random.randint(300, 400)
           good.goto(x, y)

    # Move bad Player
    for bad in bads:
        y = bad.ycor()
        y -= bad.speed # We want the ball to be falling at a slow speed
        bad.sety(y)

        # Check it off the Screen
        if y < -300:
            x = random.randint(-380, 380)
            y = random.randint(300, 400)
            bad.goto(x, y)

        # check for collision with player
        if bad.distance(player) < 20:
            x = random.randint(-380, 380)
            y = random.randint(300, 400)
            bad.goto(x, y)

ms.mainloop()
```

Comment: got this Minigame off youtube called falling skies got stuck on part 6 hope this info helps in any kind of way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your need, you want good guys and bad guys to move at different speeds.  A key to this is understanding there are two concepts of *speed* at work in the program: turtle's `speed()` method:

```
player.speed(0)
good.speed(0)
bad.speed(10)
```

This one has to do with how fast the graphics are drawn, and not what we're interested in.  And the game's own instance variable `speed` that the author hangs off of turtle instances:

```
good.speed = randint(5, 8)
bad.speed = randint(5, 8)
y -= good.speed
y -= bad.speed
```

Which probably shouldn't be called `.speed` since the turtle already has a `.speed` method.  So we'll rename this to `.velocity`.  This speed is how fast the object moves on the screen, and what we're interested in.

You changed the wrong one by setting `good.speed(0)` and `bad.speed(10)` which since they are not *drawing*, just moving turtle cursors, has little effect.  What we want to do instead is change:

```
good.velocity = randint(1, 4)  # was .speed
bad.velocity = randint(5, 8)  # was .speed
```

And fix all our other uses of the `.speed` instance variable to be `.velocity`:

```
y -= good.velocity  # was .speed
y -= bad.velocity  # was .speed
```

I've made this change, among others, to the code below.  You'll see that the good guys move about 2.5X faster than the bad guys:

```
# Our module's
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

# Functions
def go_left():
    player.direction = 'left'

def go_right():
    player.direction = 'right'

# Screen
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=800, height=600)
screen.title("Falling Piece's mini_game by Rafa94")
screen.bgcolor('purple')
screen.tracer(0)

# player
player = Turtle()
player.shape('turtle')
player.speed('fastest')
player.color('blue')
player.penup()
player.sety(-250)  # y is positive in the up direction; negative in the down direction
player.direction = 'stop'

# Create a list of good players
# Good represents good_player
goods = []  # Empty list

# Add good players
for _ in range(20):  # We are making a set of 20 players

    # We want the other players basically across from each other
    # thats we copyied the code one on -y and one on +y (first
    # player in the bottom, second player on top of Screen)

    good = Turtle()
    good.shape('circle')
    good.speed('fastest')
    good.color('red')
    good.penup()
    good.goto(-100, 250)  # y is positive in the up direction; negative in the down direction
    good.velocity = randint(1, 4)
    goods.append(good)

# Create a list of bad players
# Bad represents bad_players
bads = []  # Empty list

# Add bad players
for _ in range(20):  # we are making a set of 20 players

    # We want the other player basically across from each other
    # thats we copyied the code one on -y and one on +y (first
    # player in the bottom, second player on top of Screen)

    bad = Turtle()
    bad.shape('circle')
    bad.speed('fastest')
    bad.color('yellow')
    bad.penup()
    bad.goto(100, 250)  # y is positive in the up direction; negative in the down direction
    bad.velocity = randint(5, 8)
    bads.append(bad)

# Keyboard Binding
screen.onkeypress(go_left, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(go_right, 'Right')
screen.listen()  # Basically saying listen for keyboard input

# Main game loop
# While something is true it will repeat
while True:
    # Move player
    x = player.xcor()

    if player.direction == 'left':
        x -= 3
    elif player.direction == 'right':
        x += 3

    player.setx(x)

    # Move Good Player
    for good in goods:
        y = good.ycor() - good.velocity  # We want the ball to be falling at a smooth speed
        good.sety(y)

        if y < -300:
            # Check if it's off the Screen
            x = randint(-380, 380)
            y = randint(300, 400)
            good.goto(x, y)
        elif good.distance(player) < 20:
            # Check for collision with player
            x = randint(-380, 380)
            y = randint(300, 400)
            good.goto(x, y)

    # Move bad Player
    for bad in bads:
        y = bad.ycor() - bad.velocity  # We want the ball to be falling at a slow speed
        bad.sety(y)

        if y < -300:
            # Check if it's off the Screen
            x = randint(-380, 380)
            y = randint(300, 400)
            bad.goto(x, y)
        elif bad.distance(player) < 20:
            # Check for collision with player
            x = randint(-380, 380)
            y = randint(300, 400)
            bad.goto(x, y)

    # Update screen
    screen.update()

screen.mainloop()
```